# We couldn't parse the input provided as a DateTime value (from SharePoint to Power BI)

Tags: sharepoint, types, powerbi, datetime-format

I've connected Power BI to SharePoint 2010 list. and for DATE columns I got an error: "DataFormat.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a DateTime value.
Details:
23/03/2020"

These columns have data type both in SharePoint

[image: SharePoint]

and in Power BI

[image: Power BI].

Data type is DD/MM/YYYY

what have I already tried:

1. Changed regional setting (on local computer and on Power BI itself) - to UK
2. Choose "Using local" when changed column type.
3. changed to text format (to split column) - nothing changed
4. split the column using "/" as separator

I haven't seen any other ideas in the Internet. Maybe you have other options to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on my question. In case anyone face same issue, I post it here:

One more thing to check in such situation is go to SharePoint settings (YourSharePointSite/_layouts/15/settings.aspx). find Regional Settings and change region there to appropriate one (with the same date format).

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a nasty bug in the pbi sharepoint connector which is not in all cases able to detect/transform to correct date format. Changing API Version from 15 to 14 in M-Script does help in some cases (but not all from my experience) See also here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/SharePoint-Date-Data-getting-changed-in-Power-BI/m-p/736429